# What's the correct way to read an inputStream into a node property in JCR 2?

Tags: java, inputstream, jcr

In JCR 1 you could do:

```
final InputStream in = zip.getInputStream(zip.getEntry(zipEntryName));
node.setProperty(JcrConstants.JCR_CONTENT, in);
```

But that's deprecated in JCR 2 as detailed at http://www.day.com/maven/jsr170/javadocs/jcr-2.0/javax/jcr/Node.html#setProperty%28java.lang.String,%20java.io.InputStream%29

That says I should be using `node.setProperty(String, Binary)` but I don't see any way to turn my inputStream into a Binary.  Can anyone point me to docs or example code for this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
ValueFactory.createBinary(InputStream stream)
```

You get the ValueFactory through the Session returned by Repository.login()

Answer (score 2):

Just a tip after Rob's answer, if you wondered where to get `ValueFactory` from, you can use:

```
node.getSession().getValueFactory().createBinary(inputStream)
```